# Understanding SVG Behavior: Two Approaches, Many Questions

Tags: html, css, user-interface, svg

I've been exploring SVG text knockout effects, specifically having a video play behind the text. I've created two examples on CodePen (linked below), but each is presenting its own peculiar challenge.

The first example uses a clip path exported directly from Illustrator. The problem I'm encountering is the difficulty centering the clip path within its container. It also seems to dramatically shift location whenever the screen size changes.

In the second example, the text is clipped directly. The behavior here is also unusual: the text appears distorted and disproportionately short.

I'm open to using either approach if I can figure out these unexpected quirks. If anyone has insights, suggestions, or explanations, I'd greatly appreciate hearing them. Thank you for your time!

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Archivo+Black");
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #523ee8, #00dcaf);
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  width: 60%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0px auto;
}

svg {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  transition: 3s;
}

svg::hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

.video-container {
  margin: 40px auto;
  outline: 1px solid #dadada;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background: #fff;
}

.video-container video {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip-00);
  clip-path: url(#clip-00);
  transition: -webkit-clip-path 0.5s ease;
  transition: clip-path 0.5s ease;
  transition: clip-path 0.5s ease, -webkit-clip-path 0.5s ease;
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.video-container:hover video {
  -webkit-clip-path: none;
  clip-path: none;
}


/* Clip Path From Text */

.box-2 {
  max-width: 400px;
  margin: 25px auto;
}

.video-container-2 {
  background-color: black;
}

.m-video__video-2 {
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
  object-fit: cover;
  min-height: 240px;
}

.video-container-2 video {
  border-radius: 1.5rem;
  min-height: 240px;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip-2);
  clip-path: url(#clip-2);
}

.kot-2 {
  font-family: "Archivo Black";
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 0.02rem;
  line-height: 150% !important;
}

.video-container-2:hover video {
  -webkit-clip-path: none;
  opacity: 1;
  clip-path: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg>
    <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip-00" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" transform=" translate(50, 50) scale(.0005, 0.0009)">
              <path class="cls-1" d="m483.3,373c5.27,10.74,7.93,22.36,7.98,34.86.05,12.5-1.1,24.42-3.44,35.74-6.15,28.71-17.09,53.03-32.81,72.95-21.29,26.86-48.24,40.28-80.86,40.28h-93.02l45.85-215.92h93.02c13.28.2,24.07,1.76,32.37,4.69,14.06,4.98,24.36,14.11,30.91,27.39Zm-42.04,73.68c4.69-21.97,4.83-38.84.44-50.61-4.39-11.77-16.85-17.65-37.35-17.65h-41.6l-29.88,140.92h41.6c21.29,0,38.38-10.5,51.27-31.49,7.03-11.52,12.21-25.24,15.53-41.16Z"/>
  <path class="cls-1" d="m628.76,545.26c.1-6.05.78-12.25,2.05-18.6l3.96-20.07c2.73-13.77,2.17-22.95-1.68-27.54-3.86-4.59-12.43-6.88-25.71-6.88h-46.58l-17.87,84.67h-44.09l45.85-215.92h105.91c15.04.29,26.27,2.15,33.69,5.57,7.42,3.42,13.28,8.45,17.58,15.09,3.52,5.47,5.93,11.52,7.25,18.16,1.32,6.64,1.1,14.21-.66,22.71-2.25,10.25-7.01,20.34-14.28,30.25-7.28,9.91-17.31,16.92-30.1,21.02,9.08,4.01,14.92,9.69,17.5,17.07,2.59,7.38,2.27,18.63-.95,33.76l-3.08,14.5c-2.05,9.87-3.08,16.55-3.08,20.07,0,5.57,1.85,9.67,5.57,12.3l-1.03,5.42h-49.66c-.39-4.78-.59-8.64-.59-11.57Zm4.39-166.85h-52.44l-12.3,58.01h51.12c10.16,0,18.02-1.17,23.58-3.52,9.86-4.1,16.11-12.21,18.75-24.32,2.73-13.08.24-21.87-7.47-26.37-4.39-2.54-11.48-3.81-21.24-3.81Z"/>
  <path class="cls-1" d="m922.61,359.52c17.58,19.83,22.17,49.51,13.77,89.06-8.3,38.77-25.54,68.46-51.71,89.06-19.83,16.8-45.17,25.2-76.03,25.2s-52.69-8.4-65.48-25.2c-17.48-20.6-22.07-50.29-13.77-89.06,8.4-39.55,25.63-69.24,51.71-89.06,19.82-16.79,45.17-25.2,76.03-25.2s52.68,8.4,65.48,25.2Zm-73.54,13.04c-17.87,0-33.52,6.59-46.95,19.78-13.43,13.18-22.73,31.93-27.91,56.25-5.18,24.32-3.86,43.07,3.96,56.25,7.81,13.18,20.65,19.78,38.53,19.78s33.47-6.59,46.8-19.78,22.58-31.93,27.76-56.25c5.08-24.22,3.78-42.94-3.88-56.18-7.67-13.23-20.43-19.85-38.31-19.85Z"/>
  <path class="cls-1" d="m1077.29,556.84l-55.66-153.37-32.52,153.37h-42.04l45.85-215.92h47.31l53.91,150.73,32.08-150.73h42.04l-45.85,215.92h-45.12Z"/>
  <path class="cls-1" d="m1337.6,518.02l-8.2,38.82h-163.62l45.85-215.92h158.35l-8.2,38.23h-114.26l-9.67,45.85h104.88l-8.06,37.5h-104.88l-11.72,55.52h119.53Z"/>
        </clipPath>
    </defs>
</svg>

  <div class="box-2">
    <div class="video-container">
      <video loop autoplay muted playsinline>
        <source src="https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/mt-baker_bhtftq.webm" type="video/webm">
        <source src="https://css-tricks.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/mt-baker_cibsgl.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-2">
    <div class="video-container-2">
      <video class="m-video__video-2" autoplay muted playsinline loop data-wf-ignore="true" data-object-fit="cover">
      <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"/>
    </video>

      <svg>
      <defs>
        <clipPath id="clip-2" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
          <text class="kot-2" x="0.5" y="0.5" text-anchor="middle" dominant-baseline="middle">
            one
          </text>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
    </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/smangbuca/pen/JjeGxWX)